# bad file error while running single macro in multiple file

Tags: vba

while running this code its showing bad file name or number

I have stored all my files in "\C:\Users\20098323\Desktop\EXCL\"

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\C:\Users\20098323\Desktop\EXCL\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
        DoWork wb
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    With wb
        'Do your work here
        .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Hello World!"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ActiveWorkbook.Path &` and the first `\` from the line `Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\C:\Users\20098323\Desktop\EXCL\"`

```
Pathname = "C:\Users\20098323\Desktop\EXCL\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\C:\Users\20098323\Desktop\EXCL\"
```

This is your problem. It appends the path to the `EXCL` folder to the path of your current workbook. So you will end up with something like `C:\wherever\you\have\your\workbook\C:\Users\20098323\Desktop\EXCL\`. Instead use

```
Pathname = "C:\Users\20098323\Desktop\EXCL\"
```

Here's a tip for the future: If it gives you an error, press the debug button and it will show you the line where the error occurred. Then you can hover over the variable names and see their current value.